# Can I travel around Europe with an Australian refugee travel document?

Tags: schengen, trains, sweden, refugees

I have an Australian travel document for refugees. Do I need a visa to travel to Germany? From there, will I be able to travel to Sweden by train?

Comment: This is not clear. Do you already have a visa? What type of visa is it?

Comment: What is your actual nationality? Your country of residence is not usually relevant with visa questions.

Comment: I have an Australian travel document for refugees. Do I need a visa to travel to Germany? From there, will I be able to travel to Sweden by train  ? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base in the information found on the [German Embassy Page](https://australien.diplo.de/au-en/service/01-visa/short-term-visa/2073662)

- you do not need a visa to enter Germany, conditions are the same as for Australian citizens

For the [Swedish Embassy](https://www.swedenabroad.se/en/about-sweden-non-swedish-citizens/going-to-sweden/visiting-sweden/) I could find no clear cut statement as on the German site.

Please remember that some trains from Hamburg to Sweden, go through Denmark.

---

Holders of UN Travel Document / Titre de Voyage

- would probably be wise to check, country for country, if different conditions exist

  - Hungry may want to deal with this situation differently

I could not find a statement stating clearly if such passports holders have the same travel rights inside the Schengen area as the citizens of the country that issued the passport

- a valid question that needs clarification